# How to solve this problem? It's about how to extend a measure from a pi system to a sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Let $\nu$ and $\lambda$ be two measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ such that $\nu(A)=\lambda(A)$ for any $A\in \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\pi$-system. Assume that there are $A_i\in \mathcal(C),i=1,2,...$ such that $\cup A_i=\Omega$ and $\nu(A_i)<\infty$ for all i. I need to show that $\nu(A) =\lambda(A) $ for any $A\in \sigma(C)$. ( I have tried to show that $\{A\in \sigma(\mathcal{C})：\nu(A) =\lambda(A)\}$ is a sigma algebra but I failed. Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 1):

The collection of sets on which two measures agree is a Dynkin system.  If $\cal P$ is a $\pi$-system contained in a Dynkin system, then $\sigma(\cal P)$ is also a subset of that Dynkin system.